# How to print ordered scores in python using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing this as I have come to have troubles in my python code that shall be a test for school students, I am unable to add a working solution to allow the results from the SQLite database to be printed to the user, furthermore I would like the user to be asked how they would like it formatted e.g. alphabetically or score ascending/descending. Please help me!!!

```
import random
import sqlite3 as lite
import os

print ("Welcome to the Maths Test") 
Score = 0
question = 0

while True:
    Name = input("Please enter your name here: ")
    if Name.isdigit():
        print ("Do Not Enter a Number")
    elif Name.isalpha():
        break
while True:
    class_group = input("Please enter your class group number here: ")
    if class_group.isalpha():
        print ("Do not enter a number")
    elif class_group.isdigit():
        break       


while question < 10: 
    operation= random.randint(1,3)
    number1 = random.randint(1,25)
    number2 = random.randint(1,25)
    if operation == 1:
        print("What is", number1, "+", number2)
        answer = number1 + number2

    elif operation ==2:
        print("What is", number1, "*", number2)
        answer = number1 * number2

    else: 
        print("What is", number1, "-", number2)
        answer = number1 - number2

    while True:
        try:
            user_answer = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            print ("That is not a valid answer")
            continue 
        else:
            break

    if user_answer == answer: 
        print("Correct")
        Score += 1

    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    question += 1

    if question == 10:
        print("Well done you scored", Score, "/10")
        break
if os.path.isfile('results.db'):
    connection = lite.connect('results.db')
else:
    connection = lite.connect('results.db')

for x in range (1, 4):
    connection.execute('CREATE TABLE %s(Name INTEGER, Score TEXT);'% x)


def Pupil_Results(Name, Score):
    table = 'class%s' % class_group
    with connection:
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE name = "%s";' % Name)
        rows = cur.fetchall()

    if len(rows) > 0:
        cur.execute('UPDATE ' + table + ' SET Name = "%i" WHERE Score = "%s";' % (Name, Score))
    else:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO ' + table + '(Name, Score) VALUES (?, ?);',           (Name, Score))   
Pupil_Results(Name, Score)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is exactly your problem, what does and does not work in your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the part of your code in which you're using SQLite.

Firstly, you're connecting to the DB the same way regardless of the result of your `os.path.isfile('results.db')`, so simply connect.

Secondly, and this is more important, it is more practical to have just one table with an additional column `class_group` instead of separate tables.

Thirdly, `name` should be of type `TEXT` while `score` should be of type `INTEGER`, not the other way around.

Fourthly, the table might already exist, so you should add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the command.

Fifthly, your function should take `class_group` as an argument. It should also either take a connection as an argument, or establish a connection itself.

Here's how that part could look like:

```
def add_or_update_score(name, class_group, score):
   with lite.connect('results.db') as conn:
      # Create the table, if doesn't exist yet
      conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (name TEXT, class_group INTEGER, score INTEGER)')
      # Check if a record already exists
      if list(conn.execute('SELECT * FROM scores where name = ?', (name,))):
         # A record already exists
         conn.execute('UPDATE scores SET score = ? WHERE (name = ? AND class_group = ?)', (score, name, class_group))
      else:
         # No record exists
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name, class_group, score))
```